# Get Path root (local, mapped network drive or UNC)

Tags: powershell, path

Split-Path will easily get just the file name with -leaf, or just the full parent path with -parent, or just the root with -qualifier, but only if the path is a local path. But, is there an easy way to get the root of a path, be it a local drive letter, mapped drive letter or UNC? Basically what one would expect from **Split-Path $path -root**.

To provide some context, I am logging information and I want to provide the parent and target, so **Fonts\arial.ttf** for C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf. But, if the parent is the first child of the root, then show the whole path, so I don't want Windows\Fonts for C:\Windows\Fonts. I have the logic for doing this, I just need to get the root so I can determine if the parent of the parent is root or not. However, getting root seems to be a lot of work depending on which condition applies. No doubt there is a regEx approach that works, but I wonder if there is a native PowerShell or .NET approach that avoids the pitfalls of RegEx?

Comment: `(Get-Item $path).Psdrive.root` maybe?

Comment: `[System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot($path)` is probably easier. It work with all types you have in your question.

Comment: Matt, that's the kinda thing I was hoping for. But, quick question. I just did a test, and for C:\Path\Path it does indeed return c:\, but for \\srv\path\path it returns \\srv\path, rather than \\srv\. Is that because the concept of root is different for a UNC path? I suspect I can work around it, and also the trailing backslash in the drive letter condition without too much trouble, just wondering if I have incorrectly been considering the server to be root of a UNC all this time. ;)

Comment: If the trailing slash is an issue you can just use `.Trim("\")`. The server name is not a root. Could you place data under "\\server".. no. you need the share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing you could use for this is

```
[System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot($path)
```

It works for UNC paths, network drives and local drives. It does *not* work will all providers though. Registry for example would not work.

```
PS M:\> [System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot("C:\temp")
C:\

PS M:\> [System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot("hklm:\temp")


PS M:\> [System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot("\\s5000\Software\Windows\win.ini")
\\s5000\Software

PS M:\> [System.IO.path]::GetPathRoot("M:\DRAFT.docx")
M:\
```